# Spring JSP disappears with <form:input>

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

So I was working on a project of mine and when I tried using a `<form:input>` tag, the content of the page seems to disappear. It is just some of the content, so the nav bars and an outer box stay. I thought it is weird, since I can use it on a different page. I am not sure what is wrong on this page

JSP:

```
<div>
    <form:form method="POST" commandName="businessObjective" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/bodashboard/{id}" class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <form:input path="businessObjective" type="text" class="form-control"></form:input>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Business Objective</button>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

Controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/bodashboard/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showBoInWorkshop(
            WebRequest request,
            @PathVariable int id,
            ModelMap model
    ) {
        Workshop workshop = workshopService.findById(id);
        BusinessObjective bo = new BusinessObjective();

        String user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        User userObj = userService.findByUsername(user);
        int userId = userObj.getId();

        model.addAttribute("bo", bo);

        model.addAttribute("workshop", workshop);
        model.addAttribute("user", userObj);

        return "participant/workshop/bodashboard";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bodashboard/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processBOform(

            @ModelAttribute("businessObjective") BusinessObjective businessObjective,
            @PathVariable int id,
            BindingResult result
    ) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "participant/workshop/bodashboard";
        }

        String user = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
        Workshop workshop = workshopService.findById(id);

         BOService.addBO(businessObjective, workshop, user);
         BOService.save(businessObjective);

        return "participant/workshop/bodashboard";

    }
```

To make it clear: when I leave that  out of the .jsp it seems to be working, but obviously I want the form, when I add it, the content of the page disappears.
Hope anyone can help me with this, much appreciated

Comment: Do you have proper form tag library definition at top of jsp? example: <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

Comment: I do, yeah. Definitely checked that one. Mine is: <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

Comment: Shouldn't Path value be property of the command object? I see you have command and path both pointing to same object.

Comment: I think you are mixing up lot of stuff here, read this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the action attribute for the form:form tag as it defaults to the current URL. Next the path attribute of the form:input has to specify a property of your command object i.e businessObjective

Note your action attribute cannot specify a URI template variable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, this does not seem to be the issue though. It is the form:input in the form specifically